# Error with adding SELECT inside VALUES query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I run this command, it returns error. I specified all the values it need.

```
INSERT INTO ps_manufacturer (name, date_add, date_upd, active)
VALUES (
(SELECT name FROM prestashop_old.ps_category_lang WHERE id_lang='1' AND id_category IN (SELECT id_category FROM prestashop_old.ps_category WHERE id_parent='241')
,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
,(2));
```

Error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 2)' at line 2`

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this syntax could work, but you would to fix the typo as spotted by VBokšić.

But better yet, use the `insert ... select` syntax instead. This is more readable, and safer if ever your subquery returns more than one row (in which case the `insert ... values()` syntax would fail).

```
INSERT INTO ps_manufacturer (name, date_add, date_upd, active)
SELECT 
    name,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    2
FROM prestashop_old.ps_category_lang 
WHERE 
    id_lang='1' 
    AND id_category IN (
        SELECT id_category FROM prestashop_old.ps_category WHERE id_parent='241'
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB. It solved my problem, but can you tell what was my problem exactly?

Comment: @GMB - it will work regardless to (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d5ea1d937a6680110d55fbfa1db60f4a

Comment: @VBokšić: you are correct, thx for the fiddlde! I modified my answer accordingly. I still tend to find that the `insert ... select` syntax better fits this use case, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the second brackets in this line:

```
(SELECT name 
 FROM prestashop_old.ps_category_lang 
 WHERE id_lang='1' 
 AND id_category IN (SELECT id_category 
                     FROM prestashop_old.ps_category 
                     WHERE id_parent='241'))
```

For your new error try to change this:

```
SELECT id_category 
FROM prestashop_old.ps_category 
WHERE id_parent='241'
```

Into:

```
SELECT max(id_category)
FROM prestashop_old.ps_category 
WHERE id_parent='241'
```

And check the results of this individual query to see is this what you want to get...Or maybe it is a wrong select I am aiming at... well...

Comment: anyway, +1 for finding the problem in the original query